# How to print an array in forms (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, math

I have a mathematical problem and I´m trying to solve it, the problem is that you have 81 coins, but one is fake and it´s heavier than the others,you have to find out which one is the fake one by using a scale and doing only 4 comparisons.

I´m trying to make it like a game, when a users decides which coin will be the fake one, and the other player has to find it.

I made an array named monedasf and made all the values 0, so when the users type in the coin that wants to be the fake one, the value changes to 1. I´m trying right now to print the array, but I don´t know if I have to print it in a multiline textbox or where, here´s the code I have untill now.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int[] monedasf = new int[81];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for( int i = 0; i<=80;i++)
        {
            monedasf[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        monedasf[n] = 1;
        textBox1.Clear();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 80; i++)
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(monedasf[i]);
    }
}
```

I have only BASIC KNOWLEDGE of programming, that´s why my code might be so primitive :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 80; i++)
        textBox2.Text += monedasf[i].ToString() + " ";
}
```

If you want you can replace `" "` with any separator you want, like `"\n"` for newline.

Actually your code would work too, the problem is you were reseting `textBox2`'s text by using assign operator:

```
textBox2.Text  = Convert.ToString(monedasf[i]); // will clear and then print
textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString(monedasf[i]); // will not clear and print
```

All you need is not to reset previous text inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", monedasf);
}
```

Use string.Join which is very useful for display.